# Unable to build Spring-boot-sample-gae (deploy Spring Boot on GAE)

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, maven, spring-boot

We want to repeat the instruction of  [spring-boot-sample-gae](https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-sample-gae)  step-by-step, but we are still not able to create the WAR file with the following error message :

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project gae-demo: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.demo:gae-demo:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-legacy:jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in spring-snapshots (http://repo.spring.io/snapshot)**

Could someone let us know how to tell spring-boot-sample-gae to find this dependency?

(We already have this jar (spring-boot-legacy-1.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar) locally.)

Also, it seems that Spring boot is not compatible to GAE(Google App Engine).

Is there any way to mitigate this issue?

We wish our Spring boot project can be deployed to GAE as soon as possible.

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Spring Boot Legacy 1.1.2 locally but you're depending on 1.1.0. You need to update your POM to depend on 1.1.2:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

You say that you have 1.1.2 "locally", but it's not clear if you mean that it's in your local Maven cache. That's where it needs to be. The easiest way to get it there is:

```
git clone https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy
cd spring-boot-legacy
mvn clean install
```